# Hiding the navigation bar in Android, strange issue

Tags: android, user-interface, navigationbar

I am hiding the navigation bar on a certain activity so i can make use of the full screen.

About My App.

I have two login screens, the first one is a full login that takes all details, the second is a partial login which only asks for password based on having already gone through the main login page.

I have used this code to hide the navigation bar

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

this is from the android documents.

If i do a full login everything works perfectly and the bar is hidden.

i then override onSystemUiVisibilityChange which runs when the user swipes to make the bar active. i then reset the flags and hide the bar again after a certain amount of time. This all works great and as intended if i access the home activity from the main login activity.

However when i access the same activity but from the partial login activity the bar is still shown and only disappears after my timer has run in the

```
onSystemUiVisibilityChange.
```

So to recap both login screens login to the same home screen activity however when login in from the partial activity the navigation bar is show when it should start in the hidden state. I set the flags in the OnCreate method so it should always be called when that activity is started.

Note that when the app starts it always first hits the full login activity, i then check to see if the file with the login details exists, if it does i then move to the partial login, if not a stick with the main login